# Preserving new line inbetween xml attributes C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML which is inputed by user and I have to add some attributes to it and later return changed XML as a string.

Now the problem is, that it ignores backspaces inbetween attributes. Here is an example of what i am talking about:

XML which I get:

```
<note day="12" 
      month="11"
      year="2002"
      to="Tove"
      from="Jani" 
      heading="Reminder">
</note>
```

XML which i want to return:

```
<note day="12" 
      month="11"
      year="2002"
      to="Tove"
      from="Jani" 
      heading="Reminder"
      body="Don't forget me this weekend!">
</note>
```

XML which is actually returned:

```
<note day="12" month="11" year="2002" to="Tove" from="Jani" heading="Reminder" body="Don't forget me this weekend!">
</note>
```

Here is the code of how xmlContent (user-defined XML as a string) is loaded into XmlDocument class.

```
        XmlDocument xmlDocument= new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlContent);
```

but XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace does not seem to work when separating attributes with new line.

For creating string from XmlDocument i am using following code:

```
 using (var sw = new StringWriter())
 {
     using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
     {
        xw.WriteString(xmlDocument.InnerXml);
     }
     string stringToOutput = sw.ToString();               
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show the XML inline *as text* rather than as images. Additionally, you've shown the code to *read* the XML, but you haven't shown how you're then *writing* the XML out. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have changed XML to be displayed as a text and i have added the code of how i am writing the XML out.

Comment: Okay. First I'd suggest using `xmlDocument.Save(sw)` - you don't need to get the inner XML etc. That won't fix the problem, but it's a generally better approach IMO. However, `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace` is about preserving whitespace in element content, not between attributes. I'm not sure whether there's a way of preserving the precise layout of attributes :(

Comment: Hmm... I'd expect `XmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes` to work here, but it doesn't seem to...

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation about saving part. Will change it as you suggested.

Comment: Indeed, but the problem is that those \n\r characters are lost when loading string to XmlDocument. Therefore XmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes is not so usefull.

Comment: Well NewLineOnAttributes is intended to *create* new lines. Do you need to actually preserve all existing formatting, or is it fine to just make sure there are *always* new lines between attributes?

Comment: It actually needs to preserve all existing formating. Lets say for example WPF, where UI is defined by XAML. And user wants to add a single attribute by using my program. I want to just insert the desired attribute and maintain the same code as he specified.

Comment: Right. In that case I'll stop trying to get NewLineOnAttributes working, as it won't really help you. I understand the use case, but I don't think XmlDocument or XDocument preserve that amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at settings.IndentChars.

```
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings() 
{
    IndentChars = "\r\n"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when loading XML string to XmlDocument, all CR and NL characters are stored. Except those inbetween attributes. (\n\r is not even there for inline attributes which are separated by \n\r)

Answer (score 0):

No XML parser is going to retain the precise whitespace that occurs between attributes. It is cosmetic only. If you have an application that depends on getting the whitespace right, then that application is seriously broken and you should fix it.

There are two kinds of question we see a lot on StackOverflow.

(a) we see people reading XML without using an XML parser, typically using regular expressions. Inevitably such people can only handle incoming XML if it is formatted precisely as they expect it.

(b) we then see people trying to generate XML that is formatted precisely as someone in category (a) expects it. This can typically only be achieved by "hand-formatting" the XML rather than by using a general-purpose XML library.

These people are missing the whole point of XML, which is to use a standard format for data interchange that is supported by widely available libraries, in order to reduce costs.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say, but this program needs to help user build an XML. It helps by adding some attributes to the existing XML. There is no point if he created his own XML separating attributes by new line, and then my program totally messes indents and new lines by simply ignoring them. Great example is WPF, where user interface is defined by XAML. Lets say the user wants to add an attribute to an existing XAML using my program. Not many people would be happy, if my program totally messed their indents.

Comment: I suspect that there *are* XML parsers that do this - just like the Roslyn C# compiler is able to retain exact whitespace. The use case of "I want to be able to modify a document without completely changing all of the formatting, even if it's semantically insignificant" is a very reasonable one IMO. However, I don't believe the built-in XML APIs handle that use case. Whether there are other .NET libraries available for that, I don't know.

Comment: XML editors have this requirement, and solve it by doing their own specialized parsing (they also have a requirement to make sense of input that isn't well-formed). For generic XML parsing for ordinary applications, it would be far too complex (you'd need to retain distinctions such as single-vs-double quotes, hex-versus-decimal character references, external entity boundaries, attribute order, etc etc. It's just too difficult; though people do often ask for solutions to parts of the problem, e.g. retaining attribute order is nice-to-have.

Comment: Use case: my team has to work manually on XML files with hundreds of thousands of lines of code, so the comment placement and whitespace are helpful in navigating the large files until we develop more automated tools. Manual editing is not ideal, but until we can eliminate that we want to preserve the easy-on-the-eyes formatting.