# XMLDocument - Passing TextEdit form's text to LoadXML()

Tags: c#, forms, text, xmldocument

I have a massive amount of XML text to reorder, for M&B Bannerlord. The XML has to have a specific order to the nodes, or the whole thing crashes. And boy, are there a lot of nodes to reorder.

Got the bulk of the code down, but **XMLDocument** doesn't like taking the string from a **TextBox** form.

```
var xmldocSource = new XmlDocument();
XmlNodeList xmlnodelistNPCCharacters;

xmldocSource.PreserveWhitespace = false;
xmldocSource.LoadXml(formTextSource.Text);
```

The last line that calls **LoadXml()** throws the following error:

**System.Xml.XmlException: 'There is an unclosed literal string. Line 1035, position 37.'**

Couldn't find any info on this from Googling it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? How do I read the text from a form into an XMLDocument?

Comment: What is the text at line 1035?

Comment: Ahh, it's a split XML node. For some reason, the devs expect the following node to be formatted like so:

1035 - `<EquipmentSet id="aserai_troop_civilian_template_t3"`
1036 - `civilian="true" />`

Hmm. Is there a way to parse that, and keep that formatting?

Comment: That seems to be perfectly valid XML, see fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/wYqELD. Note that spacing between attributes is never preserved, because XML doesn't specify it as having meaning, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55897893/preserving-new-line-inbetween-xml-attributes-c-sharp